# Footer position with Elementor Header plugin by Brainstorm Force, Nikhil Chavan

Tags: wordpress, plugins, footer, custom-wordpress-pages

I have created a footer with the "Elementor Header plugin by Brainstorm Force, Nikhil Chavan". No matter what I do, it does not stick to the bottom of the page to allow the page content to display; it always covers the whole page in a mobile view.

I am using the MasterStudy theme

Is there css code or a setting in the footer page that  I can use to properly force the footer in the mobile view of the site to stay to the bottom and not cover the page?

I have tried using css below

`/`*`This is for the footer to stay at the bottom of the page`*`/`
`#footer, footer {`

`position: inherit;`
`width: 100%;`
`bottom: 0;`
`}`

`/* CSS rules for the mobile version` *`/`
`@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {`
`#footer, footer {/`* `styles for mobile */`
`position: static;`
`display: block;`
`margin-top: 20px;`
`}`